# Can anybody converge this series to give me a formula for its sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have come across this series that I can't find the sum to. I need to have a term that represents the sum of this series. Can somebody work it out for me please?
$[-1-\frac{2R}{Bxg}-\frac{3R^2}{B^2 x^2 g^2}-...-\frac{(k+1)R^k}{B^k x^k g^k}]$

Comment: $-\dfrac{B^{-k} g^{-k} R^{k+1} x^{-k} ((k+1) R-B g (k+2) x)+B^2 g^2 x^2}{(B g x-R)^2}$

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

$$\frac{d}{dr} \sum_{i=1}^{k+1}r^i=\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} \frac{dr^i}{dr} = \sum_{i=1}^{k+1} ir^{i-1} $$